# Structure string to date in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a timestamp that is currently structured as a string as so "December 18, 2022 at 5:34:06 PM UTC". I am trying to get the day out of this String and structure it to a Date format. I want to do this so I can use the `Calendar.current.isDateInYesterday()` function. When I try this as so:

```
Calendar.current.isDateInYesterday(timestamp.formatted(.dateTime.day()))
```

I get the error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Date.FormatStyle.FormatOutput' (aka 'String') to expected argument type 'Date'

I think I can't plug in a String into this function but rather an argument with date structure.

Comment: incomplete information lead to negative vote. what is timestamp? provide full code

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadII timestamp is December 18, 2022 at 5:34:06 PM UTC, I added this string in the description

Comment: you just have to give Date in argument not this ->  timestamp.formatted(.dateTime.day()) -> which contains error. first convert it to date then check if the date is not null the use date in argument

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your date input is `December 18, 2022 at 5:34:06 PM UTC`, try the following to get a date object

```swift
let dateString = "December 18, 2022 at 5:34:06 PM UTC"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' h:mm:ss a z"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from:dateString)! // this will crash if date is not parseable
```

Then you can use the `date` object in your check

```swift
Calendar.current.isDateInYesterday(date)
```

Comment: There's no need to remove literal `at`. Use this date format `"MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' h:mm:ss a z"`. And it's highly recommended to specify the `en_US_POSIX` locale for fixed date formats.

Comment: Thanks @vadian I have updated the answer based on your suggestions